# Class Definition Instance Instantiation Question

Tags: c++

I have a class *imgmanager* that allows me to load all my images exactly once, it's quite nice, and while prototyping I had all of my files in one place, so I didn't have to worry about cyclical definitions. However after separating all of my classes I have a problem.

**My Header File**

```
#ifndef IMAGEMANAGER_H   
#define IMAGEMANAGER_H
#include "Img.h"
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class imgmanager{
 protected:
 std::vector<sf::Image*> images;
 std::map<std::string,int> positions;
 public:
 sf::Image* addimg(std::string path); //relative to resources
 sf::Image* getimg(std::string path);
 int size();
 virtual ~imgmanager();
 sf::Image* operator[](int);
}imagemgr;

#endif
```

With the instance created after the } and before the ; my compiler complains at me:

So I ask: What should I do to have a global instance of my imagemgr class? Should I just make a global header file and create an instance? (in this particular case I *can* just make a global variable in my main.cpp, none of the headers require the instance)

[image: Problem Screencap]

Comment: Which part of this is specific to Windows, or to Code::Blocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't create object instances in headers.

Create your object instance in *one* source file.

If you need to access it across multiple Translation Units, put this in your header:

```
extern imgmanager imagemgr; // declaration
```

This will inform all code that can "see" the header that there exists a so-named object; but it will still only actually be defined in the one source file where you wrote:

```
imgmanager imagemgr; // definition
```

(This is analogous to the way in which you *declare* functions in a header, but *define* them in precisely one source file:

```
void f(); // declaration
void f() { ... } // definition
```

)

---

The above general advice dutifully imparted, I would now question the rationale of having a class at all if you're only going to use one, single, global instance of it. Either make it a "singleton" class, or use free functions in a namespace instead.

Comment: Tomalak, I question your last paragraph. First, Singleton **is** a class, so "you don't need a class - use Singleton" sounds strange. As for using free functions - what with all the data that an Image Manager should maintain? It leads to using static variables. I am not sure that static variables and free functions is a better design than singleton

Comment: Well thank you Tomalak, that actually quite clearly states exactly what I had anticipated the case to be (without knowing the implementation)

Comment: @davka: I said I question the rationale of having a class. I would also question the rationale of using a Singleton which, yes, is still a class. But it is, at least, a halfway house out of the situation. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you require a single global instance, i suggest you make the ImageManager a "Singleton".
I'm unsure what to do for complex types, but for a global declaration of a simple data-type you should declare the variable "extern" in the header, and instantiate it in exactly one module (.cpp file).

Comment: As was my expectation, I wasn't without doubts.

Comment: `extern` is fine for any type.