# Using same variables in several functions

Tags: c++, function, variables

In my code, due to efficiency consideration, I place a long function in it's own file (let's name it `a.cpp`).  I have also created a second file named `b.cpp` which holds another function which uses the same variables names.

I have tried to create a header file for those variables but it didn't work. Is there a way to  do that (apart from placing the functions in the same file)?

**A simple example:**

*`a.cpp`*

```
double s;

void a(){
  s = 1.0;
  printf("%f\n",s);
}
```

*`b.cpp`*

```
double s;

void b(){
  s = 2.0;
  printf("%f\n",s);
}
```

**Note**
Each of those file is, in effect a c but the whole program is c++.

Comment: "Each of those file is, in effect a c but the whole program is c++. " What does that mean?

Comment: I don't use (or almost don't use) any feature of c++. The files holds a single, long function which fills too complicated to hold in a larger, class file. Come to think about this. I can split the class file into several files with a single header right?

Comment: A "single, long function" sounds wrong.

Comment: C++ is not C, it's a multi-paradigm language, and even if you don't do any object-oriented, it's still different from C at details (even though most of C compiles as C++, which is intentional, but not to be relied upon). Decide!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write `extern double s;` in both (or in a header). This is a declaration without being a definition.

Then write `double s;` in just *one* `.cpp` file — this is where the `double` object will physically "live".

[More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202825/class-definition-instance-instantiation-question/6202913#6202913).

Answer (score 0):

Put double s; in a.cpp. Write extern s; in a.h.

Also good programming practice is a function should fit onto a screen/one side of a5.

Comment: Syntax is wrong. Also, good answering practice is to format your posts!

Comment: I agree about the fitting part but in this way I gain one less ``while`` loop.

Comment: @Yotam: And anyone coming to work on your code after you (including your future self!) gains a huge maintenance nightmare and weeks of migraines. Is one `while` loop _really_ worth it?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal I know that. This the double edge of scientific programming. I have to consider both efficiency and readability. In this case I have chosen efficiency...

Comment: @Yotam: Then you've probably chosen the wrong language, too. :)

Comment: And, incidentally, making one really long function doesn't necessarily make your program more "efficient".

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Once again, I agree the reason the function is more efficient is too complicated to describe. As for the language, c and c++ are very common in science and they are quite fast...

Comment: @Yotam: Matlab, Mathematica and similar tools are faster and better suited for many engineering/science/maths computation tasks.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, I'm not sure if this is true when simulation are considered (which is what I'm doing). I have encountered more than once with some guy who made the switch to c++ and ended up with much faster code.

Comment: @Yotam: It'll depend on the specific use case. You can't generalise based on "science".

Answer (score -3):

Put double s in a header file.

At the top of each .cpp file do:

```
#include "filename.h"
```

to introduce the variable into the cpp file for use.  It would be good to define it as static as well... but we don't go into that.

PS: You shouldn't use globals like this if avoidable.  It's not good OO design.

Comment: -1: No, this is wrong. This is no different from writing `double s;` directly in the `.cpp` files. `#include` is just a text find-and-replace operation, pre-compilation.

Comment: I have tried that and noted so (the header file part in my question)